# Mongoose: concat arrays of documents if not exist, update if exist in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following collection, and a mongoose query to concatArrays if there is no document with same exchange name, It should update if there is, but it only keeps concatenating instead of updating. I have studied the mongo, and mongoose docs, including different SO answers that did similar things. How might i achieve that with the logic i have below, also varied solutions are welcome.

```
const MarketsSchema = new Schema({ 
    
    currency_id: String,
    markets: [
        {
          exchange: "huobipro"
          volume: "1406604450.62"
        },
        {
          exchange: "binance"
          volume: "1306345450.62"
        }
   ]    

});

const top_xchanges = [

  {
   exchange: 'huobipro',
   num_trades: '0',
   volume: '17251384.69',
   volume_change: '-12490211.18',
   volume_change_pct: '-0.4200'
 },
 {
   exchange: 'cryptocom',
   num_trades: '0',
   volume: '20104559.36',
   volume_change: '-17388578.10',
   volume_change_pct: '-0.4638'
 }

]


for(let market of top_xchanges) {

     await ExchangeMarkets.updateOne({currency_id: coin },
       [{$set:{
           markets:{
              $cond: [
                {$in:[market.exchange, "$markets"]},
                {
                 map: {
                    input: "$markets",
                    as: "$markt",
                    in: {
                       $cond: {
                         if: {$in: [market.exchange, "$markt"] },
                         then: {
                             exchange: market.exchange,
                             volume: market.volume
                         },
                         else: "$markt"
                       }
                    }
                 }
                },
                {$concatArrays:["$markets",[{exchange: market.exchange, volume:market.volume }]]}
              ]
            }
        }}]
      );
}
```